# Comparing acidity in 3,4-dihydroxyfuran-2(5H)-one and 2,3-dihydroxycyclopent-2-en-1-one

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, alcohols, hydrogen, esters

I have two compounds with two hydrogens namely (a),(b),(c) and (d). I have to compare the acidity of the following hydrogens.

[image]

My approach:

I removed the hydrogen atoms one by one and compared the stabilities, as there are most resonating structures for (a) it will be most stable (most acidic too). Then followed by (b), (c) and (d).

But the answer is given different without any further explanation. Does anybody have the right approach to tackle these type of questions?

Comment: b and d should be many orders of magnitude weaker then a and c BTW both compounds are probably as acidic as typical carboxylic acid.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemistry_of_ascorbic_acid#Acidity

Comment: Order is different from what you're saying.

Comment: c must be more acidic than a, for sure. does that go well with your textbook's answers?

Comment: And you should get better textbook.

Comment: @Mithoron Can you provide a complete answer? I'm not expecting commenting and taunting.

Comment: I think you really should, even from this photo alone it doesn't look good. As far as "full answer" goes I'd need to find actual, experimental data. You'd be surprised how big difference can make stereoelectronic effects, which can be hardly seen from simple picture.

Comment: This is a question which was asked in a test to compare the acidity of hydrogens (order not values) among these compounds the information is restricted to this and no further data was given.